# How to do different traversals of an expression tree?

Tags: java

I'm trying to figure out how to do the different traversals through an expression tree. For example, if I type in " - + 10 * 2 8 3 ", I want it to print out the prefix, postfix, and infix versions of that expression.

I also need to calculate the result of the expression through a postorder traversal, which should be the evaluate function.

However, when I run my program, I only get the first character of each expression. Is my understanding of how these traversals work wrong?

EDIT: Following suggestions, I saved the result of the buildtree and also changed sc.next to sc.nextLine.

Also, every method should be recursive.

Given "- + 10 * 2 8 3", the expected answer would be:

```
prefix expression:
- + 10 * 2 8 3
postfix expression:
10 2 8 * + 3 -
infix expression:
( ( 10 + ( 2 * 8 ) ) - 3 )
Result = 23
```

I understand I haven't implemented anything with parentheses for the infix expression, but that's okay for now.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Enter a prefix expression: ");

        Node root = buildTree(sc);

        System.out.println("prefix expression: ");
        infix(root);

        System.out.println("postfix expression: ");
        postfix(root);

        System.out.println("infix expression: ");   
        infix(root);

        System.out.print("Result = ");
        evaluate(root);
    }

    static Node buildTree(Scanner sc) {
        Node n = new Node(null);
        int i = 0;
        String prefixExpression  = sc.nextLine();
        String[] temp = prefixExpression.split(" ");

        if(n.isLeaf()) {

            n.value = temp[i];
            n.left = null;
            n.right = null;

            i++;

        }

        return n;
    }

    static void infix(Node node) {

        if(node.isLeaf()){
            System.out.println(node.value);
        }

        else {
            infix(node.left);
            System.out.println(node.value + " ");
            infix(node.right);
        }

    }

    void prefix(Node node) {

        if(node.isLeaf()){
            System.out.println(node.value);
        }
        else {
            switch(node.value) {
            case "+":
                System.out.print("+");
                break;
            case "-":
                System.out.print("-");
                break;
            case "*":
                System.out.print("*");
                break;
            case "/":
                System.out.print("/");
                break;
            }
        }

        prefix(node.left);
        System.out.print(" ");
        prefix(node.right);

    }

    static void postfix(Node node) {

        if(node.isLeaf()){
            System.out.println(node.value);
        }
        else {
            postfix(node.left);
            postfix(node.right);

            switch (node.value) {
            case "+":
                System.out.print("+");
                break;
            case "-":
                System.out.print("-");
                break;
            case "*":
                System.out.print("*");
                break;
            case "/":
                System.out.print("/");
                break;
            }
        }

    }

    public static int evaluate(Node node) {

        if(node.isLeaf()) {
            return Integer.parseInt(node.value);
        }

        else {
            int leftHandSide = evaluate(node.getLeft());
            int rightHandSide = evaluate(node.getRight());
            String operator = node.getValue();

            if("+".equals(operator)) {
                return leftHandSide + rightHandSide;
            }
            else if("-".equals(operator)) {
                return leftHandSide - rightHandSide;
            }
            else if("*".equals(operator)) {
                return leftHandSide * rightHandSide;
            }
            else if("/".equals(operator)) {
                return leftHandSide / rightHandSide;
            }
            else {
                System.out.println("Unexpected problem. Error.");
            }

            return 0;

        }
    }

}
```

Here is Node.java, There's getters and setters too.

```
public class Node<E> {

    String value;
    Node<E> left;
    Node<E> right;

    Node(String value){
        left = null;
        right = null;
        this.value = value;
    }

    Node(String value, Node<E> left, Node<E> right) {
        this.value = value;
        this.left = left;
        this.right = right;
    }

    boolean isLeaf() {

        return (left == null && right == null);

    }
```

Comment: I think your main bug is using sc.next() instead of sc.nextLine().

Comment: Second, you keep calling buildTree() when you should be saving the root node.

Comment: Also, you need to decide how your tree node should be arranged while building tree, because currently, it is very difficult to understand the purpose of your evaluate method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT:**

Since your question says "*How to do different traversals of an expression tree?*, The problem I can see in your code is building the tree ( i.e. `buildTree()` method).

In order to correct this, I have used `buildExpressionTree(array)` method  to convert your prefix input to an expression tree using `Stack` data structure.

**Construction of Expression Tree:**

For constructing expression tree I have use a stack. Since in your case input is in prefix form so Loop in reverse through input expression and do following for every character.

1. If character is operand push that into stack
2. If character is operator pop two values from stack make them its
   child and push current node again.

At the end only element of stack will be root of expression tree.

Also while printing different traversals, you do not need all those if conditions to check for different operators.You can simply do the traversal as shown in my code below.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Enter a prefix expression: ");

    String prefixExpression  = sc.nextLine();
    String[] temp = prefixExpression.split(" ");
    Node n = null; 

    n = buildExpressionTree(temp);

    System.out.println("prefix expression: ");

    prefix(n);

    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("postfix expression: ");

    postfix(n);

    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("infix expression: ");

    infix(n);

    System.out.println();

    int result = evaluate(n);
    System.out.print("Result = "+ result);

}

static Node buildExpressionTree(String[] input) { 
    Stack<Node> st = new Stack(); 
    Node t, t1, t2; 
    // Traverse through every character of 
    // input expression 
    for (int i = (input.length-1); i >= 0; i--) { 

        // If operand, simply push into stack 
        if (isNumber(input[i])) { 
            t = new Node(input[i]); 
            st.push(t); 
        } else // operator 
        { 
            t = new Node(input[i]); 

            // Pop two top nodes 
            // Store top 
            t1 = st.pop();      // Remove top 
            t2 = st.pop(); 

            //  make them children 
            t.left = t1; 
            t.right = t2; 

            st.push(t); 
        } 
    } 

    t = st.peek(); 
    st.pop(); 

    return t; 
}

static boolean isNumber(String s) {

    boolean numeric = true;
    try {
        Integer num = Integer.parseInt(s);
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        numeric = false;
    }
    return numeric;
}



static void infix(Node node) {

    if( null == node) {
        return;
    }
    infix(node.left);
    System.out.print(node.value + " ");
    infix(node.right);
}

static void prefix(Node node) {

    if( null == node) {
        return;
    }
    System.out.print(node.value+ " ");
    prefix(node.left);
    prefix(node.right);

}

static void postfix(Node node) {

    if( null == node) {
        return;
    }
    postfix(node.left);
    postfix(node.right);
    System.out.print(node.value+ " ");

}

public static int evaluate(Node node) {

    if(node.isLeaf()) {
        return Integer.parseInt(node.value);
    }

    else {
        int leftHandSide = evaluate(node.left);
        int rightHandSide = evaluate(node.right);
        String operator = node.value;

        if("+".equals(operator)) {
            return leftHandSide + rightHandSide;
        }
        else if("-".equals(operator)) {
            return leftHandSide - rightHandSide;
        }
        else if("*".equals(operator)) {
            return leftHandSide * rightHandSide;
        }
        else if("/".equals(operator)) {
            return leftHandSide / rightHandSide;
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("Unexpected problem. Error.");
        }

        return 0;

    }
}
```

OUTPUT:

```
Enter a prefix expression: 
- + 10 * 2 8 3
prefix expression: 
- + 10 * 2 8 3 
postfix expression: 
10 2 8 * + 3 - 
infix expression: 
10 + 2 * 8 - 3 
Result = 23
```

Comment: How can the input prefix expression be different from the output prefix expression? How can a prefix or infix expression *end* in operators?

Comment: I have the same questions as the user above. Also, did you mean to say, "I do need all those if conditions", or did you mean "don't need"?

Comment: @user207421, thanks for mentioning this, but as OP mentioned this in question "For example, if I type in " - + 10 * 2 8 3 ", I want it to print out the prefix, postfix, and infix versions of that expression.", so I thought OP just wanted to know how to print different traversal with his code.

Comment: @Tim Chaffin, could you mentioned if your input is this "- + 10 * 2 8 3", then what output you are expecting for prefix, postfix and infix version, so I will edit my answer accordingly?

Comment: @MOnkey, I have updated the original post to show the expected prefix, postfix and infix versions of the expression.

Comment: You haven't answered my question in any way. I will simplify. What makes you think `3 2 8 10 * - +` is an infix expression?

Comment: @Tim Chaffin, you can check my above edited solution, hope it will help.

Comment: @user207421 , sorry for being late,now I have edited my answer, please check.